# SharePoint-Hosted Apps and Disaster Recovery

Tags: 2013, office-365

Microsoft's current emphasis is for us to "stay out of the GAC" and create Apps for SharePoint that clean up after themselves if uninstalled. I understand this and even agree with their suggestion that custom lists in the appweb are preferable to writing to lists in the hostweb via CSOM or REST.

I am currently building an IT Ticketing System as a app using custom lists on the appweb following Microsoft's best practices. My concern is if someone accidently uninstalls the app, all the data is lost when the app cleans up after itself.

Is anyone out there doing anything in way of disaster recovery in that event?

Is there a way to either schedule (preferable) or trigger some type of data archive?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I will suggest to create a provider hosted app so that you can backup all the data in custom databases.

Though there is a paid tool ([Layer2 Solutions](http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/Pages/default.aspx)) by which you can save all your sharepoint hosted app data in custom databases. That is a bidirectional tool. You can save lists data into DB and vice-versa.

For more information check [this link](http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/products/Pages/CC-SharePoint-Installation-and-Setup.aspx)